# Disable $ref following for json files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have JSON files that contain $ref properties. These are not JSON Schema files. When I open these files in VS Code I get errors "Failed to resolve $ref" listed in the Problems panel, because it's trying to load the file which doesn't exist (the value does not point to a file or URL). This is annoying.

Is there a way to tell VS Code not to try to resolve the $ref values?

Comment: Strange, I cannot reproduce with `VS Code 1.66.2` (without any JSON extension). Created .json file, added `$ref` as property value, name, with or without quotes (for testing), only the expected problems show up. However with `$schema`, I get a ENOENT: no such file... warning. Can you show your file, or maybe try to disable all extensions if any?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the solution is to disable the [OpenAPI (Swagger) extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=42Crunch.vscode-openapi), which parses all JSON files and tries to load the $ref attributes as if they are OpenAPI schemas.